# Как использовать ProxyPreserveHost в apache?

Tags: apache, proxy, apache2

В апаче для сайта mysiteA.com прописан

```
ProxyPass / http://mysiteB.com.
```

Таким образом страница сайта подгружает страницу с mysiteB.com. Все ссылки ведут на mysiteB.com/... Нужно сделать так, что после proxypass сохранялся адрес хоста и все ссылки вели на mysiteA.com/... Дописываю правило в апач:

```
ProxyPass / http://mysiteB.com
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

Это правило не отрабатывает. Как настроить ProxyPreserveHost?

Answer (score 3):

Решение: так как оба сайта работают на одном сервере, можно сделать ProxyPass через локалхост.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
        ServerAlias mysiteB.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost>
        ServerName mysiteA.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

директива [*proxypreservehost*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) служит для того, чтобы при передаче запроса (с помощью *proxypass*) проксируемому *http*-серверу в *http*-заголовке `host` передавалось **исходное** имя (`mysitea.com` в приведённом примере), а не проксируемое (`mysiteb.com` в приведённом примере), как происходит по умолчанию.

вероятно, наблюдаемые вами ссылки генерируются самим сайтом `mysiteb.com`. соответственно, ваш *apache* вам ничем не поможет.