# apache2 переадресация на другой порт

Tags: linux, apache

Есть несколько демонов, которые работают на сервере. Transmission работает на порту 9091 и есть gerbera которая работает на 49152.

Хочу сделать, чтобы можно было ввести `home.local/transmission`, и я попадал на порт 9091, а `home/local/media` и я попал на порт 49152.

Для transmission у меня вышло, вот строки в `proxy.conf`

```
ProxyPass /transmission http://localhost:9091/transmission
ProxyPassReverse /transmission http://localhost:9091/transmission
```

Возможно, не совсем коректно, но работает.

Пытался сделать это и для media

```
ProxyPass /media http://localhost:49152/
ProxyPassReverse /media http://localhost:49152/
```

Не работает. Можете посоветовать как это раализовать? Может есть другой более верный способ?

Comment: Как именно вы определили что не работает? `sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http` и `sudo systemctl restart apache2` надеюсь выполнили?

Comment: Возможно, стоит добавить ещё `ProxyPreserveHost On`

Comment: @ArchDemon да, все делал, и при попытке перейти на `/media` выходи такая строка

Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

И можно поподробнее про `ProxyPreserveHost` ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451341/Как-использовать-proxypreservehost-в-apache

добавьте в вопрос лог apache когда вы заходите на `/media` и `/transmission` Так же стоит убедиться что `http://localhost:9091/transmission` и `http://localhost:49152/` сами по себе работают и на них можно зайти напрямую

Comment: @ArchDemon все работает) как и через `ip 192.168.31.5:49152/` так и `home.local:49152`